# Delete old entries from table in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

a table in my MSSQL db is getting over 500MB. I would like to delete the x last entries so the table size is only 100MB. This should be a task which runs once a week. How could I do this?

Example:

Table before deleting the old entries:
[image: Table before deleting the old entries]

Table after deleting the old entries:
[image: Table after deleting the old entries]

Comment: You will need to have a server that runs a script off a cron job once a week. You will then need that script to set the logic that you desire for the deletion of the records. I would recommend setting a timestamp column that automatically updates upon inserting a new record, and simply select that and calculate a week back and delete everything that has a value less than that date.

Comment: Can somebody explain why I got a downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DATALENGTH to get the size of the data in a particular column. With a window function, you can sum up a running total of DATALENGTH values. Then you can delete all records in a table that push you past a desired max table size. Here's an example:

```
-- Sample table with a VARBINARY(MAX) column
CREATE TABLE tmp (id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, col VARBINARY(MAX))

-- Insert sample data - 20 bytes per row.
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS rn, HASHBYTES('sha1', 'somerandomtext') t
    UNION all 
    SELECT rn + 1, HASHBYTES('sha1', 'somerandomtext')
    FROM cte
    WHERE rn< 5000  
)
INSERT INTO tmp (col)
SELECT t FROM cte
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)

-- @total_bytes is the desired size of the table after the delete statement
DECLARE @total_bytes int = 200

-- Use the SUM window function to get a running total of the DATALENGTH
-- of the VARBINARY field, and delete when the running total exceeds
-- the desired table size.
-- You can order the window function however you want to delete rows
-- in the correct sequence.
DELETE t
FROM tmp t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, SUM(DATALENGTH(col)) OVER (ORDER BY id) total_size
    FROM tmp
)sq ON t.id = sq.id AND sq.total_size > @total_bytes
```

Now check what's left in tmp: 10 rows, and the total size of the "col" column matches the 200 byte size specified in the @total_bytes variable.

UPDATE: Here's an example using your sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (id INT PRIMARY KEY, contact VARCHAR(100), country VARCHAR(25))
GO

INSERT INTO tmp VALUES 
(1, 'Maria Anders', 'Germany'),
(2, 'Francisco Chang', 'Mexico'),
(3, 'Roland Mendel', 'Austria'),
(4, 'Helen Bennett', 'UK'),
(5, 'Yoshi Tannamuri', 'Canada'),
(6, 'Giovanni Rovelli', 'Italy')
GO

-- @total_bytes is the desired size of the table after the delete statement
DECLARE @total_bytes INT = 40

-- Use the SUM window function to get a running total of the DATALENGTH
-- of the VARBINARY field, and delete when the running total exceeds
-- the desired table size.
-- You can order the window function however you want to delete rows
-- in the correct sequence.
DELETE t
FROM tmp t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, SUM(DATALENGTH(contact)) OVER (ORDER BY id)
        + SUM(DATALENGTH(country)) OVER (ORDER BY id) total_size
    FROM tmp
)sq ON t.id = sq.id AND sq.total_size > @total_bytes

SELECT * FROM tmp -- 2 rows left!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE date_column < '2018-01-01';
```

This will delete all data that entered before January 2018

Comment: The date "2018-01-01" want always be the case. How could make the date always  one week before the date actual date?

Comment: Then you can use GetDate() function and substruct from it. LIke so:
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE date_column < (GetDate() -7);

Comment: In MSSQL there is a DATEADD() function, maybe this will be better solution for you:

DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete last 7days data

```
delete from table_name WHERE date_column >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I get the error: Invalid column name 'date_column'. Do you have a idea why?

Comment: @Flaqz do you have any date_column in your table?

Comment: I don't. Is it to late to create one know for the older entries?

Comment: its better to create now than never so that future data will be safe